# Possible Combination of Lists inside a Single List

Tags: python, list

Given List

```
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

I want output as 3 different list as follows

```
[1,2,3,4],[3,4,5,6],[1,2,5,6]
```

Comment: Looks like (cyclic permutations or combinations) + flatMap/concat.

Comment: I have a list of Lists ( 3 lists in a single List)  X=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]] , I want output as 3 separate lists which consists of combination of elements  of list X                               1 and 2 ie [1,2,3,4],                                                                                             2 and 3 ie [3,4,5,6] and                                                                                       1 and 3 ie [1,2,5,6]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to get all possible pairs

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

>>> list(itertools.combinations(a, 2))
[([1, 2], [3, 4]), ([1, 2], [5, 6]), ([3, 4], [5, 6])]
```

To flatten the individual elements just map over them and add the two lists

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: x[0] + x[1], itertools.combinations(a, 2)))
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 5, 6], [3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use Enumerate Function,

```
>>> x=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

>>> z = [x[index-len(x)] + x[index+1 - len(x)] for index, rec in enumerate(x)]

>>> z

>>> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 1, 2]]
```